# Get_by_natural_key throwing AttributeError?

Tags: python, django, natural-key

I'm having trouble using Django's `get_by_natural_key()` method.  (Django 1.6)

I have Items which use code numbers like this: `ABC_1234`.

Manager and Model:

```
class ItemManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, code_number_):
        return self.get(code_number=code_number_)

class Item(models.Model):
    code_number = models.CharField('Code Number',
        max_length = 10, unique = True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.code_number
    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.code_number,)
```

In my tests, I have this query...

```
Item.objects.get_by_natural_key(code_number)
```

... which throws this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key'
```

I'd like to use this `code_number` as a natural key for related model fixtures, as well as a general purpose means of querying this model.

What am I doing wrong?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't associated your custom manager with the model. You need to do so explicitly:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = ItemManager()
```

Comment: Yep, missed that.  Thank you very much!  I really appreciate it.